# Unable to write to firebase realtime database even though authentication is successful

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating a sign up form using firebase auth and realtime database.

Here is the basic layout of the form (without CSS).

```js
<script type="module">
  // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
  import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.4.0/firebase-app.js";
  import { getDatabase, set, ref, update , onValue } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.4.0/firebase-database.js";
  import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword, onAuthStateChanged, signOut , GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithRedirect, getRedirectResult, TwitterAuthProvider } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.4.0/firebase-auth.js";



  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  const firebaseConfig = {
    //CONFIDENTIAL
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const database = getDatabase(app);
  const auth = getAuth();

  signUp.addEventListener('click',(e) => {

    var email = document.getElementById('signUpEmail').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('signUpPass').value;
    // var username = document.getElementById('username').value;

    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
            .then((userCredential) => {
              // Signed in
              const user = userCredential.user;
              let dt = new Date();

              set(ref(database, 'users/' + user.uid),{
                // username: username,
                email: email,
                prem: false,
                pday: dt.getDate(),
                pmon: dt.getMonth(),
                pyear: dt.getFullYear()
              })

              alert('Signup Successful!');
              window.close();
              // window.location.replace('index.html');
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              const errorCode = error.code;
              const errorMessage = error.message;

              alert(errorMessage);
              // ..
            });

  });
```

```html
 <h1 class='status'>signup</h1>
            <input type="text" class="email" name="email" id="signUpEmail" placeholder="E-mail" />
            <input type="password" class="password" name="password" id="signUpPass" placeholder="Password" />

            <input type="submit" id='signUp' name="signUp" value="signUp" />
```

The Auth is happening successfully but the user details are not written to the realtime database.

I'm storing the following in the database:

- User email
- If they have premium subscription for my product (T/F)
- Day when their premium ends
- Month when their premium ends
- Year when their premium ends

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing data to the database (and reading data from it) is an asynchronous operation. Asynchronous here means that your main code continues to execute, while the operations runs in the background. But this also means that your `window.close()` in the main code executes before the database write completes, and in fact it seems to cancel that operation.

The solution is to wait for the database operation to complete before closing the window, similar to what you already do for `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` :

```
set(ref(database, 'users/' + user.uid),{
  // username: username,
  email: email,
  prem: false,
  pday: dt.getDate(),
  pmon: dt.getMonth(),
  pyear: dt.getFullYear()
}).then(() => { // 
  alert('Signup Successful!');
  window.close();
})
```